# Creating and deleting symbolic links

Tags: python

I'm trying to do this practice excercise:

Create a directory called 'headmap'. This directory should contain 3 files: myfile.os, read.os, write.os. 
The user enters a filename and the words 'write' or 'read', deciding where the link is going.

It should start of by doing this:
myfile.os -> read.os

And then depending on the user input change it if necessary, to:
myfile.os -> write.os

```
def symLink(file, action):
    if os.path.isdir('headmap'):
        print("headmap already exists")
    else:
        os.mkdir('headmap')
    if os.path.isfile('headmap/myfile.os'):
        print("file exists")
    else:
        os.mknod('headmap/myfile.os')
    if os.path.isfile('headmap/read.os'):
        print("file exists")
    else:
        os.mknod('headmap/read.os')
    if os.path.isfile('headmap/write.os'):
        print("file exists")
    else:
        os.mknod('headmap/write.os')
    if os.path.islink('headmap/myfile.os'):
        print("link exists")
    else:
        os.symlink('headmap/myfile.os', 'headmap/read.os')
    if action == 'write':
        os.unlink('headmap/myfile.os')
        os.symlink('headmap/myfile.os', 'headmap/write.os')
    elif action == 'read':
        os.unlink('headmap/myfile.os')
        os.symlink('headmap/myfile.os', 'headmap/read.os')

symLink('myfile.os', 'write')
```

Now, there's multiple problems.

1. It's not working. I keep getting this error message:

```
headmap already exists
file exists
file exists
file exists
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "symlink.py", line 46, in <module>
    symLink('myfile.os', 'write')
  File "symlink.py", line 38, in symLink
    os.symlink('headmap/myfile.os', 'headmap/read.os')
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'headmap/myfile.os' -> 'headmap/read.os'
```

2. The input is 'myfile.os', but how do I actually use the word 'file' instead of typing 'myfile.os' over and over? So how do I say 'headmap/file' in a way that it knows 'file' is whatever the input was.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have the arguments to symlink backwards. Think of it as analogous to a copy operation. The correct order is `os.symlink(source, destination)`.

   You also have code that creates `headmap/myfile.os` before you call `os.symlink`. `os.symlink` will fail if the destination exists. You should delete that code, or change it to use `os.unlink` to remove the file.
2. There's a lot to unpack here. I don't want to do all of your work for you, since it's a learning exercise, but I'll try to get you one step further. You can use the `os.path.join` function to combine a directory and filename, and you can give the result a name with the `=` assignment statement. Here's an example that uses the filename you passed into your `symLink` function.

```py
import os

def symLink(file, action):
    filename = os.path.join('headmap', file)
    if os.path.isdir('headmap'):
        print("headmap already exists")
    else:
        os.mkdir('headmap')
    if os.path.isfile('headmap/read.os'):
        print("file exists")
    else:
        os.mknod('headmap/read.os')
    if os.path.isfile('headmap/write.os'):
        print("file exists")
    else:
        os.mknod('headmap/write.os')
    if os.path.isfile(filename) or os.path.islink(filename):
        print("link exists")
        os.unlink(filename)
    if action == 'write':
        os.symlink('headmap/write.os', filename)
    elif action == 'read':
        os.symlink('headmap/read.os', filename)

symLink('myfile.os', 'write')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now. I figured out part 2 as well.